# Loading an external script conditionally not working, no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, external-script

Inside my condition, I have:

```
var url = "http://ads.eyeonx.ch/adserverscript/custom.min.js";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$('.ad').append(script);
console.log('ad loaded');
```

I received the console message 'ad loaded', but the ad doesn't show up and when I inspect the element, the `<script>` is not added to the div element with class `ad`.

No errors showing up with Firebug, anything obvious that I'm missing on why this wouldn't work?  I would at least expect the script tag to appear in the element.

Comment: Working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kingcodefish/748au9pL/

Comment: @KingCodeFish, yeah, you're right.  Oddly enough, the same code does not seem to be working on the web site I'm working on and reports no errors.

Comment: Not sure what would be conflicting, but it's odd that you include jQuery and don't use its full power. Try something like this: `var url = "http://ads.eyeonx.ch/adserverscript/custom.min.js";`
`$("<script>").attr({"type": "text/javascript", "src": url}).appendTo(".ad");`

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kingcodefish/748au9pL/2/

Comment: Try `jQuery('.ad').append(script)`, you may have some weirdly designed framework dependency that messes up with dollar sign. And what if this thing has a `append` method? That would explain.

Comment: @KingCodeFish, so you were right, it did actually work, it looks like the external script's document.write call was causing a conflict which apparently didn't show up in Firebug's console but did show up in Firefox's console interestingly enough.  The workaround was to use an iframe to allow the document.write, I posted this as an answer.  I still don't know why the <script> didn't show up in the inspect element but I assume it was related to Firefox blocking the document.write call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact problem to this is still unknown as to why the code wasn't showing up when inspecting the element, but I noticed a browser error in the Firefox console (not Firebug console) that complained about the external script using `document.write();`. It appears that this conflicts with the ability to add it after the page has loaded.

The solution in my case was to use an iframe. So instead of:

```
var url = "http://ads.eyeonx.ch/adserverscript/custom.min.js";
$("<script>").attr({"type": "text/javascript", "src": url}).appendTo(".ad");
```

I removed the `.ad` div and used this code to add an iframe dynamically:

```
$("<iframe>").attr({"class": "ad", "src": "/ads/ad.html", "scrolling": "no"}).prependTo('#container');
```

Which `/ads/ad.html` just contains the standard `<script></script>` stuff.

Comment: If this is your conclusion, please accept this as the answer.

Comment: @KingCodeFish, I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

'ad loaded' will get printed no matter what. Regardless of whether script is loaded successfully into 'ad' class element. You will need to print the content of the ad,

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("ad")[0].innerHTML;

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can try 'View Source' to see what is loaded on the page. As @KingCodeFish suggests, Chrome Developer tool is a powerful tool for this purpose as well.

Comment: Developer tools is a much better tool than View Source. It's available in every major modern browser and gives you a wide variety of debugging tools, especially Chrome's.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but try to make the line like this:

`$('.ad').html('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+url+'"></script>');`

The `jQuery.html([string])` function defines the inner HTML of `.ad`.

But you don't need to create variables for this...

Comment: That's a bad way to do it. It should be: `$("<script>").attr({"type": "text/javascript", "src": url}).appendTo(".ad");`

Comment: @KingCodeFish Your method is more heavy, 76 bytes. This way has 72 bytes.

Comment: @Errorever, the reason isn't length but how jQuery handles script tags.

Comment: @Errorever We're not code golfing. We're defining best practices.